# Sobrepor uma <div> a outra mantendo-as alinhadas a uma terceira <div>

Tags: html, css, imagem, div, posicionamento

Olá estou com um problema para alinhar de maneira sobreposta duas imagens.
São duas imagens A e B, sendo que a B deve estar em cima da A e ambas alinhadas na parte de baixo de outra div que está no centro da pagina. Vou deixar um exemplo pra não deixar confuso.
[![Modelo][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGWq3.png
Eu já tentei de tudo, mas não consigo alinhar as imagens de jeito nenhum, meu maior problema é muita div dentro de outra, até tentei trocar por tabela, mas o resultado deu no mesmo.
O mais próximo que cheguei foi o modelo abaixo, sendo que em position o único que deixou uma imagem sobreposta a outra foi o absolute, porem ele se alinha pela pagina e não pela div externa, que é o que preciso, até tentei colocar mais uma div contendo apenas as imagens só pra tentar alinhar e nem sei se isso piora ou ajuda.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
    div#A{
      position:absolute;
      width:auto;
    }
    div#B{
      position:relative;
      bottom:0px;
      vertical-align: middle;
      width:auto;
    }
    div#Tela{
        align-items: center;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 60%;
        height:auto;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .Btn{
        position:static;
        width:100%;
        height:auto;
    }
    .Botao{
        width:100%;
        text-align: left;
        background:#09F;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    }
```

```html
<!Doctype HTML>
<html lang = "pt-br">
<meta charset "UTF-8">
<head>
<title>Doc</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<div id="Tela">
    <div>
        <div id="A"><img id="imgA" src=""></div>
        <div id="B"><img id="imgB" src=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Btn">
        <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="btn()" class="Botao"></button>
    </div>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Obrigada pela atenção, já faz meses que estou tentando resolver isso, mas nada ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Da uma olhada aqui se é mais ou menos isso que você precisa.

https://jsfiddle.net/y1ng07oz/

Basicamente, você precisa criar um `container` (chamado de `content` no exemplo), esse `container` precisa ser **relativo**, fazendo isso, o item dentro desse container que tiver a posição **absoluta**, tomará como regra o elemento pai **relativo** para se posicionar.

Porém conteúdos absolutos não tem uma forma 'fácil' de posicionamento como encontramos com o flex layout, então é necessário fazer um pequeno cálculo na posição horizontal, como por exemplo `left: calc(50% - "tamanho da div/2");`